# How to cast an ArrayList to array of strings

Tags: java, string, arraylist, classcastexception

A problem I had:

If you want to export an ArrayList of strings into an array of strings you might try:

```
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
...
lines.add(line); // etc
...
return (String[]) lines.toArray();
```

and get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
    at wormbase.model.parser.FileParser.getDataObj(FileParser.java:45)
    at wormbase.model.parser.ModelParser.main(ModelParser.java:18)
```

referencing [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29), toArray() will return a list of objects not strings.

```
return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
```

fixes the issue.

Edit: Thanks gangnamstyleoverflow

Comment: This isn't a question, it's more of an observation...

Comment: Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask].  SO is for answerable specific questions, not a discussion board.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()])
```

no args toArray returns an Object[] check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) , thus ClassCastException.
 whereas  overloaded [toArray(T)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) returns an T[].

Comment: why `lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()])` and not `lines.toArray(new String[0])` ??

Comment: @jlordo cuz, `new String[0]` is a zero length array.

Comment: i take back what i said, just learned something new by looking at the source. Thx :)

Comment: @jlordo yepp, you are right, it would even work if toArray(new String[0]). but the resulting array will only contain the element which is at 0th index in the list. if you specify the size of the list the resulting array would have all the elements from the list. btw, OP's original question was, the cast dint work when (String[])list.toArray(), but it worked when he did list.toArray(new String[0])

Comment: no `lines.toArray(new String[0])` will also contain all elements! Check out the [source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html) line 357, now both of us learned something by this discussion :)

Comment: @jlordo ahh, you are right, thanks for letting me know, i learned something new. :)